# How can I use variables inside window before unload

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to use variables defined inside my React function in the window.addEventListner('beforeunload') function however it seems that the variables are already gone at that point. I need to do this to logout the user by calling a function inside my middleware called leaveRoom and pass in the variables "code" and "name". This is what I have tried:

```
...
149 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", e => 
150 {
151   if(!joined) return;
152   e.preventDefault();
153   leaveRoom({ code: code, username: name });
154 });
...
```

Comment: How are `joined` and `leaveRoom` defined? What does `console.log(joined)` produce at that point?

Comment: @LucaKiebel https://pastebin.com/U5pZPkwe and console.log(joined) returns undefined as its already been unloaded I assume

Comment: Can you first verify if the event is running or not, maybe try console logging something inside the event.

Comment: @PankajPrajapati it is running and console logging undefined for all the variables previously defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the best way but you can define globals.

```
window.code = "code"
window.username = "Cem"
```

after that, you can access these variables from anywhere.